# How to use an array together with jQuery.val

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to have multiple form fields on a page and put the results into an array and then get them to the database. I had that and it worked.
Then I put in an autocomplete function which gets its suggestions from the database. That works too but not if I try to use an array with it.

```
<input type="text" name="PMS" id="PMS" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="autocomplete2()">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Lägg till">
```

The above and below provide working autocomplete functionality

```
function autocomplete2() {
var keyword = $('#PMS').val();

$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax_refresh.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {keyword:keyword},
    success:function(data){                  

        $('#Sökord_list').show();
        $('#Sökord_list').html(data);                              
    }
}); }
```

However, if I try something like

```
<input type="text" name="PMS[]" id="PMS[]" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="autocomplete2()">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Lägg till">
```

and

```
function autocomplete2() {
var keyword = $('#PMS[]').val();

$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax_refresh.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {keyword:keyword},
    success:function(data){



        $('#Sökord_list').show();
        $('#Sökord_list').html(data);

    }
}); }
```

Again this might very well have something to do with my still lacking understanding of some of the basic principles of programming. Would really appreciate some help! Please tell me if you need more of the code.

Comment: You shouldn't use `[]` on your element's ID.

Answer (score 0):

@Swede

We will use []  for name attributes to store multiple values in an array and not for the **id** attributes.

Replace `id="PMS[]"` it to `id="PMS"` 
Same for selecting to `var keyword = $('#PMS').val();`

Answer (score 0):

Ids are supposed to be unique. so if at all possible I would not use same Id for multiple elements. but if you are not able to. you can do something like below to get the values.

```js
$('#mybutton').click(function(){
    let myId = 'PMS'
    let keyword = Array.from($(`[id="${myId}"]`), x => x.value)
    console.log(keyword)
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="PMS" id="PMS" value="one">
<input type="text" name="PMS" id="PMS" value="two">
<input type="text" name="PMS" id="PMS" value="three">
<input type="button" value="show vals" id="mybutton"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you for your answers! I tried that with id=PMS, name=PMS[ ] which works for one form field. However it seems to be the id that is passed to the script and not the name, since it doesn't work if I change the id to say PMS2 but I can erase the name and it still works. Even if I could figure out how to pass the name to the script instead I think it would be too much of a hassle to get it working in a neat way so I think I'll just try download an autocomplete widget where you can input multiple values in one field.